# How to save current document of Gedit using external tools?

Tags: gedit, gedit-plugin

I need to save the current document before executing some command in external tools. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

For each external tool, you can specify whether the current document (or all documents) should be saved before the tool runs.  To do this:

1. In gedit, choose `Tools->Manage External Tools...`
2. Choose a tool on the left.
3. Next to `Save:`, choose `Current Document` if you'd like the current document to be saved before the tool runs.